# Use user's Background Image as "theme"

Tags: ios, background, themes, ios7, tint

With iOs 7 Apple has introcuced lot of new thing, lots about trasparency and similar.
In "unlock screen" I saw this: [image]

Practically, this app uses user's springboard's Background as a "theme" for app influencing background, interactive and static elements (very clever thing!).
I tried to search how to do this in official documentation but I can't find it, I'm I blind?!
Has somebody an idea on how to do this? Only idea I got is to take a screenshot of springboard before app launch and "blur" it. But Ii don't know if is it possible and how...can somebody help me?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can't answer iOS 7.0 related questions outside of Apple developer forums for now.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll ask it there!

Comment: How about now, that iOS 7 is no longer under NDA?

Comment: Wrong question, I was interested to something similar Apple's weather app, background of city list. Somebody has replied to me on developer forum but I didn't go to read, I discovered that there isn't an official API, so seems that only Apple can do this...

Comment: However, what Apple did in upside screenshot is a new application of scroll views, so you do that simply with a scroll view. (I don't know how!)