# Set app-background as homescreen/springboard background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, springboard

I know that pre-ios7 one could only get few things from outside of the sandbox, however... one thing that seems more common when using Apple's apps (!) is that they use a background which is the same as the springboard background.

One example is the "Reminders" app, which uses a translucent background of the springboards background.

I have search here and on Google, but can't find an answer to my question.

Is there anyway I can do this as well in my own app?

With default iOS background:
[image: Out of the box]

Onces the springboard background is changed:
[image]

Related post:
[Use user's Background Image as "theme"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161135/use-users-background-image-as-theme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Apple uses a private API to do this.  I don't think they provide a way for developers to get to it - which is unfortunate, because it's a nice effect.

Comment: I am afraid of that too, but I am still hoping there is a solution.